# How to run batch script for 2 hours

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple batch files:

```
master1.bat
master2.bat
master3.bat
master4.bat
```

each of which when execute runs continuously in a loop until interrupted by user.
How can I make a master.bat which runs master1.bat for 1st 3 hrs->Stops it and start master2.bat and so on.
i.e `Master.bat` should do the following

```
Start master1.bat
 After 3 hrs Stop master1.bat
 Start master2.bat
 after 3 hrs Stop master2.bat
 start master 3.bat
 after 3 hrs Stop master3.bat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `taskkill` you can selectively kill a process by title.And there's a lot of ways to delay in batch file

So:

```
::start a bat with master1 title
start "master1" master1.bat
::wait 3 hrs
typeperf "\System\Processor Queue Length"  -sc 1 -si 18000 >nul
:: kill a window with title master1
TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq master1*"
```

and you can repeat this for the rest of the scripts.